# Flutter Dropdown Button overflow

Tags: flutter

I am trying to realise a dropdown button in flutter. However, the icon that is displayed at the end for the dropdown is always pushed out of the object, how can I fix this so that the content remains within the widget?[image: Here you can see that the indicator arrow is behind the dropdown button (above the amount widget)]

Here you can see that the indicator arrow is behind the dropdown button (above the amount widget)

The code for this looks like this

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>? dropdownItems =
        loadDropdownItems();

//The Row with the widgets causing the Problems:
Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 10,
                            child: ButtonTheme(
                              alignedDropdown: true,
                              child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                                value: selectedIngredient,
                                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                                  if (newValue != null) {
                                    ref
                                        .read(selectedIngredientProvider.notifier)
                                        .state = newValue;
                                  }
                                },
                                items: dropdownItems,
                                hint: Text('Ingredient'),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Select Ingredient',
                                  contentPadding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color:
                                      Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color:
                                      Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 7,
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: amountController,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Amount',
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color:
                                        Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color:
                                        Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(ingredientUnit(ref, selectedIngredient!)),
                        ],
                      ),


//method to load all dropdown items
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> loadDropdownItems() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> list = [];
    for (Objects object in allObjects) {
      list.add(DropdownMenuItem(
        value: object.name,
        child: Text(ingredient.name, overflow: TextOverflow.fade)),
      );
    }
    return list;
  }
```